# You used to wear me, you might still do

Tags: riddle

> You used to wear me,
>
> you might still do.
>
> If I never existed,
>
> there won't be you.

Who am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is a

> Parent

You used to wear me,

> "Wear" here means to exhaust, and parents are often worn by their responsibilities to a young child.

you might still do

> Some people reading this might still exhaust their parents.

If I never existed
There won't be you

> If either of your parents never existed, neither would you.

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not correct however this was the first thing i thought of

> umbilical cord